# DbSet<User>.Where() always return null EFCore2.2

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

I want to get a query from database using linq but it return null or empty every time;

```cs
var user = await _identityDb.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserName == user.UserName); // this return null but user exist even in debuger
var users = _identityDb.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName); // this return empty
```

`update`
this return users

```cs
var users = _identityDb.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == u.UserName.ToString());
```

but this return empty

```cs
var users = _identityDb.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName.ToString());
```

Comment: Do it return data without the where?   Is the user name you are searching in the results without the where?

Comment: What is the type of UserName property? What are the requirements for UserName matching?

Comment: @jdweng `_identityDb.Users.ToArray()` return list of users;

Comment: @MustafaGursel UserName is `string`

Comment: Are you using the correct namespace "microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"? Also, if oyu search the first or default without filter does it give you an user?

Comment: @Dr.Roggia yes. i get answer without filter or with `u=>true` filter

Comment: What type is `user`? What type is `user.UserName`? What value does `user.UserName.ToString()` return? (note that I'm not asking about `u` or `u.UserName`, I'm specifically asking about the `user` variable and its content)

Comment: Then user.UserName.ToString() does not equal "MustafaGursel"

Comment: assuming `UserName` is a `string`, `u.UserName == u.UserName.ToString()` is equivalent to `u.UserName == u.UserName` and all users match that predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of some encryption method I used. so SQLServer couldn't handle it. I just removed encryption on username column.

Answer (score 2):

`==` is case sensitive.

If you want to compare the two strings case insensitive, you should use the overload of [`String.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Equals_System_String_System_StringComparison_) that accepts a `StringComparison`:

```
var users = _identityDb.Users
                .Where(u => u.UserName
                                .Equals(user.UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

You can learn more about the `StringComparison` Enum [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison).

Comment: We don't know the requirement for user names. Maybe they want case sensitive matching.

Comment: Use `string.Equals` with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` for case insensitive matching (or `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`). `ToUpper()` is slower, more resource-intensive and may give incorrect results with specific Unicode characters.

Comment: didn't worked. i used same object to create and find user. but nothing...

Comment: @DemiDev If your `user` is null as you mentioned in your question, it's no surprise that the `Where` yields no results. Use this string comparison on the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` as well.

Comment: it was first thing i used and after a this problem i changed it to this one. not working

Comment: If `.Users` is a EF collection, the whole thing from the question will be translated to SQL, in which case the case sensitivity of the database is the thing that matters. Will the code in this answer even translate to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently every `User` has a property `UserName`. Alas you forgot to tell us the type of the property. Because of the name of the identifier and your comparison with a string, I assume that `UserName` is a string.

If `UserName` is already a string, why do you compare it `UserName.ToString()`?

The following returns all users from your DbSet of user that have a value of `UserName`, equal to `UserName.ToString`:

```
var users = _identityDb.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == u.UserName.ToString());
```

Because `UserName` is a string, `UserName.ToString()` will always equal `UserName`. In that case the query will return all `Users`.

Now you seem to have an object `user` of class `User`. We don't know whether or not this `user` is a `User` in your collection of `_identityDb.Users`.

The following will return all users in `_identityDb.Users` that have a UserName equal to `user.UserName`

```
var users = _identityDb.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == user.UserName);
```

If `user` is in `_identityDb.Users` you will certainly find at least one `User` with this name, maybe even more than one. If you still don't find one, try debugging by typing the name of the user:

```
string userName = user.UserName;
var users = _identityDb.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == userName);
```

A final possibility: it could be that `UserName` is not a string, or that you defined your own `ToString()`. If you omitted this information, then my advice would be to spend some time on learning how to ask a question properly.